# Get & Set Angular share Data

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to share data from one component to another by using a service that will be directly injected in the ts file of each component.

the probleme is i can't display the data in message component

**service**

```
export class ProductSharingDataService {

  private productName!:any;

  setRowName(selectedTableRowData:Product[]){
    this.productName = selectedTableRowData;
  }

  getRowName():Product[]{
    return this.productName;
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

parents component
**page.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-page',
  templateUrl: './product-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-page.component.css'],
  providers: [ProductSharingDataService] // i injected my service here
})
export class ProductPageComponent {

  public selectedArrayParent!: Product;

  constructor(private productSharingDataService: ProductSharingDataService) {
  }

  receive($event: any) {
    this.selectedArrayParent = $event
    this.productSharingDataService.setRowName = $event;
  }

}
```

child component **message.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-message',
  templateUrl: './product-message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-message.component.css'],
  providers: [ProductSharingDataService] // i injected my service here
})
export class ProductMessageComponent {
  
  @Input() public selectedArrayEnfant1!: Product;
  
  name:any;
  
  constructor(private productSharingService: ProductSharingDataService) {
    this.name = this.productSharingService.getRowName;
    console.log(this.name);
  }
  
  // ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  
  // }
  
  // ngOnInit(): void {
  
  // }
}
```

in my message component when i try console.log i have nothing in my console why ?

Comment: Does `ProductSharingDataService` has the `@Injectable` decorator in your source code?

Comment: @DivisionByZero yes `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})`

Comment: Ok, just wanted to be sure. Your error might be that you simply get the name in the message constructor once. An Observable/BehaviorObject would be a better  approach in my opinion.

Comment: you are talking about BehaviorSubject rxjs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the component level providers

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-message',
  templateUrl: './product-message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-message.component.css'],
})
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-page',
  templateUrl: './product-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-page.component.css'],
})
```

Otherwise each time your service will be re-instantiated.

`@Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' })` will make sure the same instance of the service is injected to consumer components.

And you should use a subject based approach for sharing data.

```js
export class ProductSharingDataService {

  readonly productName$!:any = new BehaviorSubject('');

  setRowName(selectedTableRowData:Product[]){
    this.productName.next(selectedTableRowData);
  }

  getRowName():Product[]{
    return this.productName.getValue();
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-page',
  templateUrl: './product-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-page.component.css'],
})
export class ProductPageComponent {

  public selectedArrayParent!: Product;

  constructor(private productSharingDataService: ProductSharingDataService) {
  }

  receive($event: any) {
    this.selectedArrayParent = $event
    this.productSharingDataService.setRowName($event.name);
  }

}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-message',
  templateUrl: './product-message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-message.component.css'],
})
export class ProductMessageComponent {
  
  @Input() public selectedArrayEnfant1!: Product;
  
  name$:any = this.productSharingService.productName$;
  
  constructor(private productSharingService: ProductSharingDataService) {}
```

and inside the `product-message.component.html` you should use the name with an `async` pipe:

```html
<div> {{name$ | async}} </div>
```

Comment: if i remove message component providers will it continue to work ?

Comment: Yes you should remove it from both of the components.

Comment: this does not help me to display the reslutat in my component message

Comment: I updated my answer with a full example. But you code has errors like this line `this.productSharingDataService.setRowName = $event;` . `setRowName` is a method and you're trying to assign something to it rather than calling it. Is this intentional?

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind. But if you have a getter/setter function in your service the value you are getting/setting should be private in my opinion.

Comment: thanks for you help, but inside the `new BehaviorSubject();` i have this error : Expected 1 arguments, but got 0, An argument for '_value' was not provided.

Comment: oops, yes you need to initialise it; updated

Comment: @DivisionByZero I made it readonly there out of lazyness and made the method return the snapshot value. I agree that private is better but that becomes a "clean code" discussion :-) I'll leave that up to the OP

Comment: I'm almost there, it displays me in my html [object Object] why ?

Comment: probably because the `$event` is an object. What does it look like if you console log it?

Comment: @eko I did something like this : `receive($event: any) {
    this.selectedArrayParent = $event
    let t = this.productSharingDataService.setRowName($event);
    console.log(t);
  }` I have undefined it's the right thing to do ?

Comment: no no why would you assign the method to a variable. I just meant `receive($event: any) {  console.log($event); ...`

Comment: I have an object here is the object: 
`{
position: 5, 
name: "Boron", 
weight: 10.811, 
symbol: "B"
}`

Comment: ok then you should be providing `$event.name`, right?

Comment: It works. Thank you very much for your help and time spent on my problem.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)